# Create a web page in a folder on SharePoint

Tags: library, sharepoint-page

I want to store a web page in a folder, is it possible?

**Note**: I don't want to create the folder in the Page library rather I want it under Documents.

Comment: you can create pages in "Site Pages" or "Pages" libraries in SharePoint site. "Documents" is a default document library to store documents in it. But you can create pages in this default document library after adding pages related content type in it. See this https://www.kalmstrom.com/tips/sharepoint-online-course/Content-Types-Use.htm link to add content type in document library.